# How can I disable default ordering temporarily in Visual FoxPro?

Tags: sql, oledb, visual-foxpro

I am doing a search where I want to keep the natural order in order to maintain ranking.  Here's my code query:

```
SELECT buyer_id, first, last, ALLTRIM(address) AS address1, city, state FROM BUYERMAST.DBF WHERE first = '{0}' AND last = '{1}' UNION 
SELECT buyer_id, first, last, ALLTRIM(address) AS address1, city, state FROM BUYERMAST.DBF WHERE phone = '{6}' UNION 
SELECT buyer_id, first, last, ALLTRIM(address) AS address1, city, state FROM BUYERMAST.DBF WHERE first LIKE '{0}' AND last LIKE '{1}' UNION 
SELECT buyer_id, first, last, ALLTRIM(address) AS address1, city, state FROM BUYERMAST.DBF WHERE address LIKE '{2}' AND city LIKE '{3}' UNION 
SELECT buyer_id, first, last, ALLTRIM(address) AS address1, city, state FROM BUYERMAST.DBF WHERE first = '{0}' OR last = '{1}' OR address = '{2}' OR city = '{3}' OR state = '{4}' OR zip = '{5}' OR phone = '{6}' or email = '{7}'"
```

The first select in the union returns me an exact match whereas the last select returns a very general match.  The problem is that the results are always returned sorted by buyer_id.  I cannot alter the existing tables/indexes, and I see that there are several indexes with the buyer_id being the first one.  I would like to "disable" the index order if possible so that the results from the first select are returned first and the subsequent selects are actually appended to the previous.  Is this possible?

P.S. The unions, by default, are distinct, and if I add a "rank" column to each select and order by that, it will leave duplicate results because the rank column is distinct between each select query.

Comment: It is tempting to consider removing the oledb and vfp tags.  In some sense, it is basically just an SQL question and it might get a wider audience.  But, of course, the very next comment would be "What database?".

Comment: That's interesting. It would be implementation-dependent, so some database engines may return it in that order while others don't (and it could even change from release to release for a database).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a SINGLE query that has all the qualifiers in ONE query, but additional columns as flags WHERE they qualified... Since your last union has "OR" values across the board, just use that as the WHERE, but the specific criteria as FLAGs on HOW it was qualified, then you can keep a single entry per person but have it flagged as "howeverMatched" to analyze through.

```
SELECT 
      buyer_id, 
      first, 
      last, 
      address AS address1, 
      city, 
      state,
      ( first = '{0}' AND last = '{1}' ) as ExactNameMatch,
      ( phone = '{6}' ) as PhoneMatch,
      ( LIKE( first, '{0}' ) AND LIKE( last, '{1}' )) as LikeNameMatch,
      ( LIKE( address, '{2}' ) AND LIKE( city, '{3}' )) as LikeAddressMatch
   FROM 
      BuyerMast
   WHERE 
         first = '{0}' 
      OR last = '{1}' 
      OR address = '{2}' 
      OR city = '{3}' 
      OR state = '{4}' 
      OR zip = '{5}' 
      OR phone = '{6}' 
      OR email = '{7}'
      OR ( first LIKE '{0}' AND last LIKE '{1}' )
      OR ( address LIKE '{2}' AND city LIKE '{3}' )
```

Its not liking the "LIKE" in the name match qualifiers...  so the LikeNameMatch and LikeAddressMatch are the culprits...  HOWEVER, VFP does have a FUNCTION, so I've changed them

```
from   first LIKE '{0}'
to     LIKE( first, '{0}' )
```

similar with the rest.

Comment: I believe that is what @Zach was referring to in the "P.S." when he mentioned adding a rank column.

Comment: @MarkWilkins, yup, misinterpreted that element.

Comment: @Zach, take a look at revised answer. This should get what you want with a single entry per person without complexities of all the unions too.

Comment: Thanks - I'm taking a look at this now.

Comment: @DRapp - I don't think it likes the boolean columns we're adding.  I'm getting the error "Function name is missing )".  I believe it has to do with the _Match columns.  Perhaps we're assigning them inappropriately? or perhaps VFP doesn't like doing comparisons in the column selection area?

Comment: Actually I just tried `SELECT ('a' = 'a') AS IsTrue FROM Buyermast` and it worked.  Still investigating.

Comment: @Zach, See revised answer with LIKE() function vs Field LIKE something

Comment: @DRapp - That worked.  I think I can live with this. :) I assumed you expected me to add on `ORDER BY ExactNameMatch DESC, PhoneMatch DESC, LikeNameMatch DESC, LikeAddressMatch DESC`, which I did to get the desired results.  Thanks a bunch! It's even more efficient this way without the unions.  Thanks for the new perspective.

Comment: @Zach, ONE ADJUSTMENT... I think I had the function backwards... the WILDCARD option entry should be the FIRST parameter being COMPARED to the second (per VFP documentation).  Ex: LIKE( "Ch*", SomeColumn ), not LIKE( SomeColumn, "Ch*" )... just confirm with your data and alter as needed.

Comment: @DRapp, I'll adjust as needed.  Thanks! [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3xx56bh(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible to accomplish that directly. The goal is to put some kind of implied order on the results without an ORDER BY clause, and the problem is that a relation has no specific order. So unless the query depends on implementation specific behavior of the database engine, you probably can't get there directly.

It is possible that a `UNION ALL` would preserve the original order, although I don't know that is guaranteed.  If so (or even if not you could use the rank idea mentioned in the OP to do an ORDER BY), you could then "manually" remove the duplicates after the query.

Another possibility that would result in an extremely ugly query and possibly hard to optimize would be to again use a UNION ALL (or the rank idea) to get the results for each condition but add to each subsequent condition the `NOT` of the previous conditions.  In other words, make each individual SELECT choose only the rows it is specifically adding to the final result:

```
SELECT ... WHERE condition1 UNION ALL
SELECT ... WHERE condition2 and NOT (condition1) UNION ALL
SELECT ... WHERE condition3 and NOT(condition1) and NOT (condition2)
etc. and on into a very ugly query
```

Note that in the above example that if UNION ALL does not indeed preserve the order, you could add in a rank value into each select and then ORDER the final result by that value (the query itself would have the uniqueness built into it with all the `not(condition)` clauses.

Comment: I agree.  Very ugly!  Haha, and I'm not so sure the UNION ALL would preserve the order either.

Comment: Zach: Indeed!  I haven't had time to study it, but I think @DRapp's answer looks promising. If you find it works, I will upvote it.